# Unable to mount: exit code 1

Tags: udisks

I am trying to mount some of my hard drive and USB but getting this error

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdd1 on /media/sdd1
```

how can I fix this?

There is no drive by the name of `/dev/sdd1` and no `/media/sdd1` cause when I try to unmount/detach it I get:

```
root@sysadmin-MS-7592:/home/sysadmin# udisks --unmount /dev/sdd1
Unmount failed: Device is not mounted

root@sysadmin-MS-7592:/home/sysadmin# udisks --detach /dev/sdd1
Detach failed: Device is not a drive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the drive by running the below command,

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1
```

Make sure that you created a sdd1 directory inside `/media`.

Comment: That worked but when you try to eject the drive I get a error Error unmounting: umount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
umount: only root can unmount /dev/sdd1 from /media/sdd1

Comment: try `sudo umount /dev/sdd1` to unmount.

Comment: error occurs because you have to run both the command with superuser priveleges(`sudo`).

Comment: I am clicking the eject button; I want to avoid using the terminal to mount and unmount. When I click the eject button I get:Error unmounting: umount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
umount: only root can unmount /dev/sdd1 from /media/sdd1.... I am unable to unable any of my drive normally

Comment: try `sudo nautilus` command on terminal.The mounted drive will be appeared on the devices list.Right click on the drive and then click unmount.Your drive will be unmounted.

Comment: Great stuff @AvinashRaj - thanks if I face anymore problem! I will let you know .... This will have to work for now until I figure out how to fix it back normally